# Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()

Tags: c, printf

I keep stumbling on the format specifiers for the printf() family of functions.  What I want is to be able to print a double (or float) with a maximum given number of digits after the decimal point.  If I use:

```
printf("%1.3f", 359.01335);
printf("%1.3f", 359.00999);
```

I get

```
359.013
359.010
```

Instead of the desired

```
359.013
359.01
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Floating point inexactness really means you should do the rounding yourself.  Take a variant of R and Juha's answer (which don't quite handle the trailing zeroes), and fix it up.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This can't be done with the normal `printf` format specifiers.  The closest you could get would be:

```
printf("%.6g", 359.013); // 359.013
printf("%.6g", 359.01);  // 359.01
```

but the ".6" is the *total* numeric width so

```
printf("%.6g", 3.01357); // 3.01357
```

breaks it.

What you *can* do is to `sprintf("%.20g")` the number to a string buffer then manipulate the string to only have N characters past the decimal point.

Assuming your number is in the variable num, the following function will remove all but the first `N` decimals, then strip off the trailing zeros (and decimal point if they were all zeros).

```
char str[50];
sprintf (str,"%.20g",num);  // Make the number.
morphNumericString (str, 3);
:    :
void morphNumericString (char *s, int n) {
    char *p;
    int count;

    p = strchr (s,'.');         // Find decimal point, if any.
    if (p != NULL) {
        count = n;              // Adjust for more or less decimals.
        while (count >= 0) {    // Maximum decimals allowed.
             count--;
             if (*p == '\0')    // If there's less than desired.
                 break;
             p++;               // Next character.
        }

        *p-- = '\0';            // Truncate string.
        while (*p == '0')       // Remove trailing zeros.
            *p-- = '\0';

        if (*p == '.') {        // If all decimals were zeros, remove ".".
            *p = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you're not happy with the truncation aspect (which would turn `0.12399` into `0.123` rather than rounding it to `0.124`), you can actually use the rounding facilities already provided by `printf`. You just need to analyse the number before-hand to dynamically create the widths, then use those to turn the number into a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void nDecimals (char *s, double d, int n) {
    int sz; double d2;

    // Allow for negative.

    d2 = (d >= 0) ? d : -d;
    sz = (d >= 0) ? 0 : 1;

    // Add one for each whole digit (0.xx special case).

    if (d2 < 1) sz++;
    while (d2 >= 1) { d2 /= 10.0; sz++; }

    // Adjust for decimal point and fractionals.

    sz += 1 + n;

    // Create format string then use it.

    sprintf (s, "%*.*f", sz, n, d);
}

int main (void) {
    char str[50];
    double num[] = { 40, 359.01335, -359.00999,
        359.01, 3.01357, 0.111111111, 1.1223344 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num)/sizeof(*num); i++) {
        nDecimals (str, num[i], 3);
        printf ("%30.20f -> %s\n", num[i], str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The whole point of `nDecimals()` in this case is to correctly work out the field widths, then format the number using a format string based on that. The test harness `main()` shows this in action:

```
  40.00000000000000000000 -> 40.000
 359.01335000000000263753 -> 359.013
-359.00999000000001615263 -> -359.010
 359.00999999999999090505 -> 359.010
   3.01357000000000008200 -> 3.014
   0.11111111099999999852 -> 0.111
   1.12233439999999995429 -> 1.122
```

Once you have the correctly rounded value, you can once again pass that to `morphNumericString()` to remove trailing zeros by simply changing:

```
nDecimals (str, num[i], 3);
```

into:

```
nDecimals (str, num[i], 3);
morphNumericString (str, 3);
```

(or calling `morphNumericString` at the end of `nDecimals` but, in that case, I'd probably just combine the two into one function), and you end up with:

```
  40.00000000000000000000 -> 40
 359.01335000000000263753 -> 359.013
-359.00999000000001615263 -> -359.01
 359.00999999999999090505 -> 359.01
   3.01357000000000008200 -> 3.014
   0.11111111099999999852 -> 0.111
   1.12233439999999995429 -> 1.122
```

Comment: Note, this answer assumes that the decimal place is `.` In some locales, the decimal place is actually a `,` comma.

Comment: There is actually a minor typo here - 
p = strchr (str,'.'); 
should actually be 
p = strchr (s,'.');  
To use the function param rather than the global var.

Comment: Using too many digits may trigger unexpected results... for example "%.20g" with 0.1 will display garbage. What you need to do if you don't want to surprise the users is start from say 15 digits and keep incrementing until `atof` gives back the same value.

Comment: @6502, that's because there's no such thing as 0.1 in IEEE754 :-) However, it won't cause a problem (at least for that value) since the resultant `0.10000000000000000555` will be `0.1` when stripped back. The problem may come if you have a value slightly under such as if the closest representation of `42.1` was `42.099999999314159`. If you really wanted to handle that, then you'd probably need to round based on the last digit removed rather than truncate.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It's of course true that 0.1 doesn't exist :-) but if you pass 0.1 to `atof` you get a number and when passing the number to `printf` you get something that most users find ugly and surprising. Indeed this was what happened in Python for quite a long time, until they implemented a better handling that produces the most compact decimal representation that when parsed gives back the same number and this is much appreciated (in the sense that people stopped complaining :-D). This is normally implemented by just looping over a "%*g" formatting operation followed by a parsing operation.

Comment: @6502, added a solution that uses the facilities already found in `printf` but without any looping. I think that gives a better representation though, of course, there may be *other* aspects that have escaped my attention. No doubt the SO swarm will make me aware of them if so :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: There's no need to dynamically create a format string for `printf`-like functions as they already support dynamic parameters (`*` special character): for example `printf("%*.*f", total, decimals, x);` outputs a number with the dynamically specified total field length and decimals.

Answer (score 70):

To get rid of the trailing zeros, you should use the "%g" format:

```
float num = 1.33;
printf("%g", num); //output: 1.33
```

After the question was clarified a bit, that suppressing zeros is not the only thing that was asked, but limiting the output to three decimal places was required as well. I think that can't be done with sprintf format strings alone. As [Pax Diablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/#277810) pointed out, string manipulation would be required.

Comment: See the MSDN help page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ecbz014(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Tomalak: This does not do what I want.  I want to be able to specify a maximum number of digits after the decimal point.  This is: I want 1.3347 to be printed "1.335" and 1.3397 to be printed "1.34"
@xtofl: I had already checked that, but I still can't see the answer to my problem

Comment: Author want style 'f' not style 'e'. 'g' can use style 'e' : From documentation : Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision.

Answer (score 20):

I like the answer of R. slightly tweaked:

```
float f = 1234.56789;
printf("%d.%.0f", f, 1000*(f-(int)f));
```

'1000' determines the precision.

*Power to the 0.5 rounding.*

**EDIT**

Ok, this answer was edited a few times and I lost track what I was thinking a few years back (and originally it did not fill all the criteria). So here is a new version (that fills all criteria and handles negative numbers correctly):

```
double f = 1234.05678900;
char s[100]; 
int decimals = 10;

sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
printf("10 decimals: %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);
```

And the test cases:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <math.h>

int main(void){

    double f = 1234.05678900;
    char s[100];
    int decimals;

    decimals = 10;
    sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
    printf("10 decimals: %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);

    decimals = 3;
    sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
    printf(" 3 decimals: %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);

    f = -f;
    decimals = 10;
    sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
    printf(" negative 10: %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);

    decimals = 3;
    sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
    printf(" negative  3: %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);

    decimals = 2;
    f = 1.012;
    sprintf(s,"%.*g", decimals, ((int)(pow(10, decimals)*(fabs(f) - abs((int)f)) +0.5))/pow(10,decimals));
    printf(" additional : %d%s\n", (int)f, s+1);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output of the tests:

```
 10 decimals: 1234.056789
  3 decimals: 1234.057
 negative 10: -1234.056789
 negative  3: -1234.057
 additional : 1.01
```

Now, all criteria are met:

- maximum number of decimals behind the zero is fixed
- trailing zeros are removed
- it does it mathematically right (right?)
- works (now) also when first decimal is zero

Unfortunately this answer is a two-liner as `sprintf` does not return the string.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to trim trailing zeroes, though?  It can gladly spit out something like 1.1000.

Comment: The question and my answer are not the originals anymore... I will check later.

Comment: Failed test cases: 1.012 with formatter "%.2g" will result in 1.012 instead of 1.01.

Comment: @Jeroen: I think the floats fail also at some point when numbers get bigger... but basically typecasting to long, long long or int64 should work.

Comment: It does not work correctly for negative values > −1, for example −0.12345... (casting to int loses the minus sign). Also, maybe introduce a function for your tests instead of copying the three lines of code many times?

Comment: Used ``"%s%d%s", x < 0 && int(x) >= 0 ? "-" : ""`` to fix the minus sign that was lost for small negative values, but found another failure: 0.000010000000043 and decimals=10 yields "0e-05".

Comment: 1.005 with two decimals yields "1" not "1.01" as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just do this?

```
double f = 359.01335;
printf("%g", round(f * 1000.0) / 1000.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of the highly voted solutions suggest the `%g` conversion specifier of `printf`. This is wrong because there are cases where `%g` will produce scientific notation. Other solutions use math to print the desired number of decimal digits.

I think the easiest solution is to use `sprintf` with the `%f` conversion specifier and to manually remove trailing zeros and possibly a decimal point from the result. Here's a C99 solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char*
format_double(double d) {
    int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%.3f", d);
    char *str = malloc(size + 1);
    snprintf(str, size + 1, "%.3f", d);

    for (int i = size - 1, end = size; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == '0') {
            if (end == i + 1) {
                end = i;
            }
        }
        else if (str[i] == '.') {
            if (end == i + 1) {
                end = i;
            }
            str[end] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Note that the characters used for digits and the decimal separator depend on the current locale. The code above assumes a C or US English locale.

Comment: −0.00005 and 3 decimals will yield "−0" which may or may not be desired. Also, maybe make "3" a parameter for the convenience of others?

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this (might have rounding errors and negative-value issues that need debugging, left as an exercise for the reader):

```
printf("%.0d%.4g\n", (int)f/10, f-((int)f-(int)f%10));
```

It's slightly programmatic but at least it doesn't make you do any string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

I search the string (starting rightmost) for the first character in the range `1` to `9` (ASCII value `49`-`57`) then `null` (set to `0`) each char right of it - see below:

```
void stripTrailingZeros(void) { 
    //This finds the index of the rightmost ASCII char[1-9] in array
    //All elements to the left of this are nulled (=0)
    int i = 20;
    unsigned char char1 = 0; //initialised to ensure entry to condition below

    while ((char1 > 57) || (char1 < 49)) {
        i--;
        char1 = sprintfBuffer[i];
    }

    //null chars left of i
    for (int j = i; j < 20; j++) {
        sprintfBuffer[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution but it gets the job done, assigns a known length and precision and avoids the chance of going exponential format (which is a risk when you use %g):

```
// Since we are only interested in 3 decimal places, this function
// can avoid any potential miniscule floating point differences
// which can return false when using "=="
int DoubleEquals(double i, double j)
{
    return (fabs(i - j) < 0.000001);
}

void PrintMaxThreeDecimal(double d)
{
    if (DoubleEquals(d, floor(d)))
        printf("%.0f", d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 10, floor(d * 10)))
        printf("%.1f", d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 100, floor(d* 100)))
        printf("%.2f", d);
    else
        printf("%.3f", d);
}
```

Add or remove "elses" if you want a max of 2 decimals; 4 decimals; etc.

For example if you wanted 2 decimals:

```
void PrintMaxTwoDecimal(double d)
{
    if (DoubleEquals(d, floor(d)))
        printf("%.0f", d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 10, floor(d * 10)))
        printf("%.1f", d);
    else
        printf("%.2f", d);
}
```

If you want to specify the minimum width to keep fields aligned, increment as necessary, for example:

```
void PrintAlignedMaxThreeDecimal(double d)
{
    if (DoubleEquals(d, floor(d)))
        printf("%7.0f", d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 10, floor(d * 10)))
        printf("%9.1f", d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 100, floor(d* 100)))
        printf("%10.2f", d);
    else
        printf("%11.3f", d);
}
```

You could also convert that to a function where you pass the desired width of the field:

```
void PrintAlignedWidthMaxThreeDecimal(int w, double d)
{
    if (DoubleEquals(d, floor(d)))
        printf("%*.0f", w-4, d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 10, floor(d * 10)))
        printf("%*.1f", w-2, d);
    else if (DoubleEquals(d * 100, floor(d* 100)))
        printf("%*.2f", w-1, d);
    else
        printf("%*.3f", w, d);
}
```

Comment: Take `d = 0.0001`: then `floor(d)` is `0`, so the difference is bigger than 0.000001, so `DoubleEquals` is false, so it will _not_ use the `"%.0f"` specifier: you will see trailing zeros from `"%*.2f"` or `"%*.3f"`. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found problems in some of the solutions posted.  I put this together based on answers above.  It seems to work for me.

```
int doubleEquals(double i, double j) {
    return (fabs(i - j) < 0.000001);
}

void printTruncatedDouble(double dd, int max_len) {
    char str[50];
    int match = 0;
    for ( int ii = 0; ii < max_len; ii++ ) {
        if (doubleEquals(dd * pow(10,ii), floor(dd * pow(10,ii)))) {
            sprintf (str,"%f", round(dd*pow(10,ii))/pow(10,ii));
            match = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( match != 1 ) {
        sprintf (str,"%f", round(dd*pow(10,max_len))/pow(10,max_len));
    }
    char *pp;
    int count;
    pp = strchr (str,'.');
    if (pp != NULL) {
        count = max_len;
        while (count >= 0) {
             count--;
             if (*pp == '\0')
                 break;
             pp++;
        }
        *pp-- = '\0';
        while (*pp == '0')
            *pp-- = '\0';
        if (*pp == '.') {
            *pp = '\0';
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n", str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.999, 2 ); // prints -2
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.006, 2 ); // prints -1.01
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.005, 2 ); // prints -1
    printf("\n");
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.005, 2 ); // prints 1 (should be 1.01?)
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.006, 2 ); // prints 1.01
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.999, 2 ); // prints 2
    printf("\n");
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.999, 3 ); // prints -1.999
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.001, 3 ); // prints -1.001
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.0005, 3 ); // prints -1.001 (shound be -1?)
    printTruncatedDouble( -1.0004, 3 ); // prints -1
    printf("\n");
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.0004, 3 ); // prints 1
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.0005, 3 ); // prints 1.001
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.001, 3 ); // prints 1.001
    printTruncatedDouble( 1.999, 3 ); // prints 1.999
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first try at an answer:

```
void
xprintfloat(char *format, float f)
{
  char s[50];
  char *p;

  sprintf(s, format, f);
  for(p=s; *p; ++p)
    if('.' == *p) {
      while(*++p);
      while('0'==*--p) *p = '\0';
    }
  printf("%s", s);
}
```

Known bugs: Possible buffer overflow depending on format. If "." is present for other reason than %f wrong result might happen.

Comment: Your known bugs are the same that printf() itself has, so no problems there.  But I was looking for a format string that allowed me doing what I wanted, not a programmatic solution, which is what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on above:

1. Eliminates period for case (10000.0).
2. Breaks after first period is processed.

Code here:

```
void EliminateTrailingFloatZeros(char *iValue)
{
  char *p = 0;
  for(p=iValue; *p; ++p) {
    if('.' == *p) {
      while(*++p);
      while('0'==*--p) *p = '\0';
      if(*p == '.') *p = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

It still has potential for overflow, so be careful ;P

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should use
 `printf("%.8g",value);`

If you use `"%.6g"` you will not get desired output for some numbers like.32.230210 it should print `32.23021` but it prints `32.2302`

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue, double precision is 15 decimal, and float precision is 6 decimal, so I wrote to 2 functions for them separately

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

std::string doublecompactstring(double d)
{
    char buf[128] = {0};
    if (isnan(d))
        return "NAN";
    sprintf(buf, "%.15f", d);
    // try to remove the trailing zeros
    size_t ccLen = strlen(buf);
    for(int i=(int)(ccLen -1);i>=0;i--)
    {
        if (buf[i] == '0')
            buf[i] = '\0';
        else
            break;
    }

    return buf;
}

std::string floatcompactstring(float d)
{
    char buf[128] = {0};
    if (isnan(d))
        return "NAN";
    sprintf(buf, "%.6f", d);
    // try to remove the trailing zeros
    size_t ccLen = strlen(buf);
    for(int i=(int)(ccLen -1);i>=0;i--)
    {
        if (buf[i] == '0')
            buf[i] = '\0';
        else
            break;
    }

    return buf;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    double a = 0.000000000000001;
    float  b = 0.000001f;

    printf("a: %s\n", doublecompactstring(a).c_str());
    printf("b: %s\n", floatcompactstring(b).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
a: 0.000000000000001
b: 0.000001
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed that and the first answer from paxdiablo does the trick. But I was not needing truncating and the version below is maybe slightly faster?
Starting to search end of string (EOS) after the ".", only one placement of EOS.

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf
//adapted from paxdiablo (removed truncating)
char StringForDouble[50];
char *PointerInString;
void PrintDouble (double number) {
  sprintf(StringForDouble,"%.10f",number); // convert number to string
  PointerInString=strchr(&StringForDouble[0],'.'); // find decimal point, if any
  if(PointerInString!=NULL) {
    PointerInString=strchr(&PointerInString[0],'\0'); // find end of string
    do{
      PointerInString--;
    } while(PointerInString[0]=='0'); // remove trailing zeros
    if (PointerInString[0]=='.') { // if all decimals were zeros, remove "."
      PointerInString[0]='\0';
    } else {
      PointerInString[1]='\0'; //otherwise put EOS after the first non zero char
    }
  }
  printf("%s",&StringForDouble[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to calculate the *required* precision that would not result in trailing zeroes for a given double value and pass it to the `"%1.*f"` format in printf().
This can even be done as one-liner:

```
int main() {
    double r=1234.56789;
    int precision=3;
    printf(L"%1.*f", prec(r, precision), r);
}

int prec(const double& r, int precision)
{
    double rPos = (r < 0)? -r : r;
    double nkd = fmod(rPos, 1.0); // 0..0.99999999
    int i, ex10 = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < precision; ++i)
        ex10 *= 10;
    int nki = (int)(nkd * ex10 + 0.5);

    // "Eliminate" trailing zeroes
    int requiredPrecision = precision;
    for (; requiredPrecision && !(nki % 10); )  {
        --requiredPrecision;
        nki /= 10;
    }
    return requiredPrecision;        
}
```

And here is another `%g` solution. You should always provide a format precision that is "wide enough" (default is only 6) and round the value. I think this is a nice way to do it:

```
double round(const double &value, const double& rounding)  {
    return rounding!=0 ? floor(value/rounding + 0.5)*rounding : value;
}

printf("%.12g" round(val, 0.001)); // prints up to 3 relevant digits
```

Comment: 2nd one does not compile--test your code before posting please

Answer (score 0):

Generally `sprintf/std::format` or any other formatting function does not provide such functionality out of box, however - there exists `%g` [format specifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm), but it uses total amount of number including numbers before comma specifier.

With `%.2g` format of number `23.45` would result in plain `23`, not `23.45` as you would expect. (mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277810/2338477))

One approach is to calculate amount of digits before comma using [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/determining-how-many-digits-there-are-in-an-integer-in-cplusplus).

Example of full formatting could be following:

```
#include <iostream>


int GetExponentStringLength(double d)
{
    d = abs(d);
    if (d < 1)
    {
        return 0; //zero is not counted as valid decimal from sprintf perspective
    }

    int r = (int)log10(d) + 1;
    return r;
}

void printEnoughDecimals(double d, int precision)
{
    printf("%.*g\n", GetExponentStringLength(d) + precision, d);
}


int main()
{
    printEnoughDecimals(1.2345, 2);
    printEnoughDecimals(1234.456, 2);
}

will print:
1.23
1234.46
```

Somehow similar approach can be used with other formatting functions.

Answer (score -1):

Your code rounds to three decimal places due to the ".3" before the f

```
printf("%1.3f", 359.01335);
printf("%1.3f", 359.00999);
```

Thus if you the second line rounded to two decimal places, you should change it to this:

```
printf("%1.3f", 359.01335);
printf("%1.2f", 359.00999);
```

That code will output your desired results:

```
359.013
359.01
```

*Note this is assuming you already have it printing on separate lines, if not then the following will prevent it from printing on the same line:

```
printf("%1.3f\n", 359.01335);
printf("%1.2f\n", 359.00999);
```

The Following program source code was my test for this answer

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{

    printf("%1.3f\n", 359.01335);
    printf("%1.2f\n", 359.00999);

    while (true){}

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The question was about creating one format string that omits trailing zeros, not to have different format strings for each case.