# printing floating point numbers in D

Tags: printf, d

It's been quite a while since I last used [D Programming Language](http://digitalmars.com/d), and now I'm using it for some project that involves scientific calculations.

I have a bunch of floating point data, but when I print them using `writefln`, I get results like: `4.62593E-172` which is a zero! How do I use string formatting % stuff to print such things as 0?

Right now I'm using a hack:

```
    if( abs(a) < 0.0000001 )
        writefln(0);
    else
        writefln(a);
```

it does the job, but I want to do it using the formatting operations, if possible.

**UPDATE**

someone suggested `writefln("%.3f", a)` but the problem with it is that it prints needless extra zeros, i.e. `0` becomes `0.000` and `1.2` becomes `1.200`
Can I make it also remove the trailing zeros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: This can't be done with printf format specifiers.

Since D uses the same formatting as C99's `vsprintf()`, you find your answer in this thread: [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
writefln("%.3f", a);
```

Comment: this prints 1 as 1.000 and 0 as 0.000, can i make it remove trailing zeros?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so. Standard (C, D, whatever) format specifiers for floating point numbers come in the form %x.yf, where x is the width of the number being displayed, and y is the precision beyond the decimal point.

Comment: Not with writefln/printf, anyway. Did you try D's streams?

Answer (score 1):

Federico's answer should work, for more information check the [format specifiers](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_format.html#format-string) section.

Answer (score -1):

I see you are currently using Phobos, however what you are trying to do is supported in Tango.

```
Stdout.formatln("{:f2}", 1.2);
```

will print "1.20"