# Limit a double to two decimal places

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, formatting

How do I achieve the following conversion from double to a string:

```
1.4324 => "1.43"
9.4000 => "9.4"
43.000 => "43"
```

i.e. I want to round to to decimal places but dont want any trailing zeros, ie i dont want

```
9.4 => "9.40" (wrong)
43.000 => "43.00" (wrong)
```

So this code which I have now doesn't work as it displays excess zeros:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", total]
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985791/round-double-value-to-2-decimal-places so I think it should be unmarked as a duplicate. This question is about how to limit to a *maximum* of two decimal places whereas the other question is how to limit to *always* two decimals. The latter is easy and already mentioned in original question.

Comment: Yea it's not a duplicate. Someone just excited about their mod powers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/). See the [Data Formatting Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/)'s chapter on [Number Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html).

Answer (score 35):

You made simple mistake. This will work:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2lf", total]
```

Comment: It works, but how?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to probably roll your own. I've had to do this in C before since there's no way to get the behavior you want with `printf` formatting.

It doesn't appear to be much easier in Objective-C either. I'd give this a try:

```
NSString *ftotal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", total];
while ([ftotal hasSuffix:@"0"]) {
    ftotal = [ftotal subStringToIndex [ftotal length]-1];
}
if ([ftotal hasSuffix:@"."]) {
    ftotal = [ftotal subStringToIndex [ftotal length]-1];
}
```

or this (possibly faster) variant:

```
NSString *ftotal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", total];
if ([ftotal hasSuffix:@".00"]) {
    ftotal = [ftotal subStringToIndex [ftotal length]-3];
} else {
    if ([ftotal hasSuffix:@"0"]) {
        ftotal = [ftotal subStringToIndex [ftotal length]-1];
    }
}
```

The `stringWithFormat` guarantees there will always be a `".nn"` at the end (where `n` is a digit character). The `while` and `if` simply strip off trailing zeros and the trailing decimal if it was an integer.

Obviously, you may want to put it in a function or class so you can get at it from anywhere without having to duplicate the code all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with objective C, but this isn't possible with standard printf-style formatting.

Using %g would sort-of work, but for large or small numbers it would use scientific notation (eg 9.6e+6, 4.2e-7) rather than decimal notation.

The [equivalent question was asked for C/C++ here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf), and in that case the answer is to use %f and then strip any trailing 0's from the string.  Not exactly elegant.

Comment: Hey, that was my answer you're calling inelegant :-) Actually it's a lot more elegant in Objective-C since strings are actually strings rather than C char arrays with all their foibles.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure that [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:f] stringValue] does exactly what you want.