# Suppressing unnecessary zeros

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, stringwithformat

I would like to make a string with stringWithFormat from a double value, without the unnecessary zero at the end.

Examples:

1. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",2.344383933];`
2. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",2.0];`

expected results:

1. `2.344383933`
2. `2`

Which is the correct format ?

Thank you.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113408/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places

Comment: Yes, I would suppress all the 0 after the decimal point if meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNumberFormatter`

```
[numberFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",0]]
```

Sample:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

NSLog(@"1: %@",[numberFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",2.344383933]]);
NSLog(@"2: %@",[numberFormatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",2.0]]);
```

Results:

`1: 2.344383933`

`2: 2`

Comment: You are using `NSNumberFormatter` really in a strange way. Why would you even use `stringWithFormat`? Why are you using `numberFromString` if your result should be a `string`? What you want to do is to set `maxFractionalDigits` to `8` and just call `stringFromNumber:`.

Comment: Make an answer to your suggestion to make this post even more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated class for number formatting, `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8

print("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(2.344383933))")
print("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(2.0))")
```

`NSNumberFormatter` will also bring localization (decimal points, grouping separators).