# Round double value to 2 decimal places

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a double value as 22.368511
I want to round it to 2 decimal places. i.e. it should return 22.37

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to return that value with 2 decimal places? or display the value with 2 decimal places?

Comment: Actually I just need to display it

Answer (score 191, accepted):

As in most languages the format is

```
%.2f
```

you can see more examples [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/nslog/nslogformat.html)

---

***Edit***: I also got this if your concerned about the display of the point in cases of 25.00

```
{
    NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmt setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.342]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.3]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0]]);
}
```

> ```
> 2010-08-22 15:04:10.614 a.out[6954:903] 25.34
> 2010-08-22 15:04:10.616 a.out[6954:903] 25.3
> 2010-08-22 15:04:10.617 a.out[6954:903] 25
> ```

Comment: On iOS, I had to use `setPositiveFormat:`, because `setFormat:` method did not exist (defined only for Mac), but still - great answer, saved me hours of experimenting, so +1 and big thanks to you :)

Comment: One problem: is doesn't round, but truncates. Presumably, using the input value provided by the questioner with your code, the result would not be what he expected (22.37)—rather (22.36).

Comment: But you can not use it for further calculation

Answer (score 73):

You can use the below code to format it to two decimal places

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:22.368511]];

NSLog(@"Result...%@",numberString);//Result 22.37
```

Swift 4:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.roundingMode = .up

let str = String(describing: formatter.string(from: 12.2345)!)

print(str)
```

Comment: In swift 4 :
let str = String(describing: formatter.string(from: 12.2345)!)

Comment: Is it possible that do not increase 6 to 7 in 22.36 value of result?

Comment: @ShahbazAkram Yes. The roundingMode has many other options as well e.g., NSNumberFormatterRoundDown, NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfDown etc.

Answer (score 30):

```
 value = (round(value*100)) / 100.0;
```

Comment: I believe this is the most correct answer - he asked to just round it - not to convert it into a string at the end (or do a double conversion back to double afterwards).

Answer (score 15):

```
[label setText:@"Value: %.2f", myNumber];
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [NSDecimalRound](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1412204-nsdecimalround) function

Comment: that is useful if your rounding the value, (which I also thought was the question at first) but the comments show that hmthur wats to control the display only ...

Answer (score 11):

**In Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.2:**

```
let pi:Double = 3.14159265358979
String(format:"%.2f", pi)
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To remove the decimals from your double, take a look at this output

**Obj C**

```
double hellodouble = 10.025;
NSLog(@"Your value with 2 decimals: %.2f", hellodouble);
NSLog(@"Your value with no decimals: %.0f", hellodouble);
```

The output will be:

```
10.02 
10
```

**Swift 2.1 and Xcode 7.2.1**

```
let hellodouble:Double = 3.14159265358979
print(String(format:"Your value with 2 decimals: %.2f", hellodouble))
print(String(format:"Your value with no decimals: %.0f", hellodouble))
```

The output will be:

```
3.14 
3
```

Answer (score 4):

I was going to go with Jason's answer but I noticed that in My version of Xcode (4.3.3) I couldn't do that.  so after a bit of research I found they had recently changed the class methods and removed all the old ones.  so here's how I had to do it:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.342]]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:number]; instead of NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:number];

```
+(NSString *)roundToNearestValue:(double)number
{
    NSNumber *aNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:number];

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *string = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:aNumber];        
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift there is a simple solution if you can't either import Foundation, use round() and/or does not want a String (usually the case when you're in Playground):

```
var number = 31.726354765
var intNumber = Int(number * 1000.0)
var roundedNumber = Double(intNumber) / 1000.0
```

**result: 31.726**

Answer (score 2):

I use the solution posted by [Umberto Raimondi](https://medium.com/ios-swift-development-notes/swiftbites-15-rounding-floating-point-numbers-to-specific-decimal-places-62970d746081)  extending type Double:

```
extension Double {
    func roundTo(places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter* f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[f setFormat:@0.00"];

// test
NSNumber* a = @12;
NSString* s = [f stringFromNumber:a];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```