# how to format float value to have only 2 digits after decimal in iOS?

Tags: ios, floating-point, truncate

I am facing this silly problem :

I want to use a float value for some comparison...Unfortunately the value I get from the slider is something like  14.545645646 ... and the other values I have are like 5.2, 54.9 etc....

I am not very sure what to do here .... is there a way to truncate after 2decimal digits ?

Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Round or truncate? They are different operations. What do you want?

Comment: i would prefer rounding...actually... :-s..I got the answer for truncating..what about rounding ? any idea ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985791/round-double-value-to-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiply by 100, cast to an int, and divide by 100.0?

Answer (score 2):

Above solution don't work. It get same value.

It is lot easier to use the formatter %.2f

float abc = 0.4343322
NSLog(@"Formatted value : %.2f", abc);

Comment: Above solution *should* work. If it doesnt, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSLog(@"Distance i meters: %.02f", [itemloc distanceFromLocation:current]/1000);
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.