# displaying Java double value

Tags: java, eclipse, number-formatting, system.out, numberformatter

here's a piece of Java code:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class javaTests
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double decimal = 0.60;

        System.out.println(decimal);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to print 0.60, but the compiler prints 0.6. How can I get this to print 0.60? Thanks!

Comment: try `System.out.println(String.format( "%.2f", decimal ) );`

Comment: Thank you @singhakash, this worked perfectly! could you briefly explain what `String.format` does?

Comment: See the java formatter class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html  
%[flags][width][.precision]conversion   "." is for padding , 2 specifies the number of digits and f for float

Comment: @BjC sorry for the late reply did you check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).Its better explaines there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round double value to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985791/round-double-value-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
double decimal = 0.60;
System.out.println(formatter.format(decimal));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the way you were trying to do it.  A `double` only stores a number, it doesn't store the precision that number was written with.  You can change the formatting of the output (e.g. `System.out.printf("%.2f", value)`, or you can store the value in a different data type (e.g. `BigDecimal`, which does draw that distinction), but there is no difference in the double value `0.6` and the double value `0.60`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also format using the String class.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1.2f",.60));
```

The format method takes multiple parameters. The first argument is always the format string, which uses below syntax.

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

Please refer to the java documentation for detail information on Formatter

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax