# Round Float Value without increasing last digit Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I want to convert latitude value to string but upto 2 decimal value. I already implement this mehtod

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", nearestRegion.center.latitude]
```

But problem is that it convert `31.415546` to  `31.42` means increase last digit. Result should be `31.41`. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985791/round-double-value-to-2-decimal-places May be It will help You

Comment: Check my answer brother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
NSNumber *numb = @(31.415546);
NSString *numberAsString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numb];
NSLog(@"The value is - %@", numberAsString);
```

The output value is

[image]

Comment: @ShahbazAkram Did you check my answer? This answer is faster and better than my answer? It's funny ;)

Comment: @trungduc you are right. you are given faster, easy and short code. this is lengthy code.

Answer (score 3):

Subtracting `nearestRegion.center.latitude` 0.005 before printing will resolve problem.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", nearestRegion.center.latitude - 0.005]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
float myFloat= 2345.678990;
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[format setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat]]];
NSLog(@"After change Float Value:%@",string);
```

The Output is: 2345.67

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
float f = 31.415546f;
f = truncf(f * 100.0) / 100.0;
NSString* floatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", f];
NSLog(@"%@",floatString);
```

this will return, 
31.410000

but 31.41 will be equal to  31.410000

so this will satisfy your purpose

Hope this helps

Comment: Basically i want to compare two string. So how to remove all zearo from last?