# Display two decimal places in Objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit a double to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113408/limit-a-double-to-two-decimal-places)

I want to display numbers in specific format in Objective C. Here, I just want to show the numbers with two precision.

Suppose I have numbers like 25.5;

Then I want show number as given below.

`25.5 => 25.50`

Comment: Display numbers how?  To a text field? To a log?

Answer (score 10):

Replace to

```
taxLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [sum doubleValue]];
```

Comment: //To Do: 2 decimal places
        NSNumber *sum = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([refreshOrderResponse.TaxPrice doubleValue] + [refreshOrderResponse.ServiceChargePrice doubleValue])];
        
        taxLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [sum stringValue]];

Comment: try this taxLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [sum doubleValue]];

Comment: @Hector +1 for your kind support.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at the [NSNumberFormatter class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).