# Remove extra zeros when converting a double to a string in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, double, numbers, trim

So when I convert a double to a string using something like this:

```
double number = 1.1;
text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", number];
```

The variable `text` ends up printing something like this: `1.100000`. I realize that this is because of the way the computer stores the value however I need an easy way to remove those extra zeros and, if need be, the decimal as well if the number turns out to an integer.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf

Comment: check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469614/remove-more-than-2-trailing-zero/7470191#7470191

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/index.html) and [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with it's [usesSignificantDigits](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-SW5) property. It is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm seems like what I want, but I can't get this to work. I'm a bit of a noob at Objective-C. Anyway I can a bit of example code?