# Use printf to format floats without decimal places if only trailing 0s

Tags: c, printf

Is it possible to format a float in C to only show up to 2 decimal places if different from 0s using printf?

Ex:

12 => 12

12.1 => 12.1

12.12 => 12.12

I tried using:

```
float f = 12;
printf("%.2f", f)
```

but I get

12 => 12.00

12.1 => 12.10

12.12 => 12.12

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the `%g` format specifier:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  float f1 = 12;
  float f2 = 12.1;
  float f3 = 12.12;
  float f4 = 12.1234;
  printf("%g\n", f1);
  printf("%g\n", f2);
  printf("%g\n", f3);
  printf("%g\n", f4);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
12
12.1
12.12
12.1234
```

Note that, unlike the `f` format specifier, if you specify a number before the `g` it refers to **the length of the entire number** (not the number of decimal places as with `f`).

Comment: you still want to have the `%.2g` so that it limits to 2 decimal places.

Comment: By the way, for the `f` format specifier the number represents decimal digits, but for `g` it is the total length of the number.

Comment: oops my mistake. How would that work if you don't know how many digits are before the decimal point? I know you could find it and use a variable size but that seems like a lot of work for that.

Comment: That's a good point. The question Mike Kwan linked to has a brittle solution for that. Since the OP hasn't stated that as a specification I probably shouldn't have put a number in there. We'll see what the OP says :-)

Comment: wow that seems like a complicated why of doing it. I was thinking something like `sprintf(temp, "%f", f); temp2 = strchr(temp, '.'); i = temp2-temp; printf(%.*g\n", (i+2), f);` but I don't know if that will actually work. I think I'll go try it.

Comment: Worked for me. obviously you have to define all the variables correctly.

Comment: What is unfortunately not good about `%g`, is that it may truncate number and you will lose precision, for example `printf("%g", 1363262708.988428)` will give you `1.36326e+09`, however with `%f` it will print correctly (exactly `1363262708.988428`).

Comment: @ivanzoid: the problem can be solved by using `"%.14g"` instead of just `"%g"` (I don't think the number 14 is too significant; that's what I found in Lua's source code).

Comment: The problem with %g is that it treats precision as the number of significant digits, not the number of digits after the decimal point: `printf("%.2g",0.01234)` prints `0.012`. It seems that if you want the correct (expected) behavior, you need to roll your own function.

Answer (score 7):

From our discussion in the above answer here is my program that works for any number of digits before the decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    float f1 = 12.13;
    float f2 = 12.245;
    float f3 = 1242.145;
    float f4 = 1214.1;

    int i = 0;
    char *s1 = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 20));
    char *s2 = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 20));

    sprintf(s1, "%f", f1);
    s2 = strchr(s1, '.');
    i = s2 - s1;
    printf("%.*g\n", (i+2), f1);

    sprintf(s1, "%f", f2);
    s2 = strchr(s1, '.');
    i = s2 - s1;
    printf("%.*g\n", (i+2), f2);

    sprintf(s1, "%f", f3);
    s2 = strchr(s1, '.');
    i = s2 - s1;
    printf("%.*g\n", (i+2), f3);

    sprintf(s1, "%f", f4);
    s2 = strchr(s1, '.');
    i = s2 - s1;
    printf("%.*g\n", (i+2), f4);

    free(s1);
    free(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the output

```
12.13
12.24
1242.15
1214.1
```

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, here's a simple ObjC implementation:

```
// Usage for Output   1 — 1.23
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ — %@", [self stringWithFloat:1], 
                                       [self stringWithFloat:1.234];

// Checks if it's an int and if not displays 2 decimals.
+ (NSString*)stringWithFloat:(CGFloat)_float
{
    NSString *format = (NSInteger)_float == _float ? @"%.0f" : @"%.2f";
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:format, _float];
}
```

%g wasn't doing it for me — this one yes :-) Hope it's useful to some of you.