# How to not show unnecessary zeros when given integers but still have float answers when needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, format-specifiers, stringwithformat

I have an app I'm developing and one of my features is giving answers in float or double values when needed and an integer when the answer is a whole number

so for example if the answer comes out to 8.52 the answer becomes 8.52 but when the answer is 8 the answer is 8 instead of 8.0000, i don't want it to show all the extra 0s.

```
- (IBAction) equalsbutton {
NSString *val = display.text;
switch(operation) {

    case Plus :
        display.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qi",[val longLongValue]+[storage longLongValue]];

    case Plus2 :
        display.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[val doubleValue]+[storage doubleValue]];
```

this code doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These specifiers are [standard IEEE format specifiers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), which means that you can do things like `%.2f` to only show 2 decimal places on a float variable.

You could also convert it into an `int`, and then use the `%d` format specifier if you wanted to do it that way.

Here's also [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) on the subject.

**EDIT:** Based on your comment on the other post, it looks like you're looking for `%g`, which will essentially remove the extraneous 0's from floats.

```
display.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",[val doubleValue]+[storage doubleValue]];
```

I found the answer here: [Use printf to format floats without decimal places if only trailing 0s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628645/use-printf-to-format-floats-without-decimal-places-if-only-trailing-0s)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method call:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [val doubleValue] + [storage doubleValue]];
```

Comment: I did that but it seems to make it to where the 0 specifies the number of all decimals it can use. I i use .1f then an answer 8.555555 will come out to 8.5 only i want to allow the answer 8.555555 but not answers like 8.500000 i want to show no extra zeros in the decimals

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Formatting

Here is a way that I did this when I needed to display currency (but whole numbers if the currency was a round number.

First we get the money amount as a string

```
NSString *earnString = _money.payout.displayableAmount;

NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString
                                   stringWithCapacity:earnString.length];
```

//scan the string to remove anything but the numbers (including decimals points)

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:earnString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet
                           characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}
//create an int with this new string
int earnInt = [strippedString intValue];
```

//if the string is less than 100 then we only had "change" so display that amount 
    if(earnInt < 100){
        //Dollar amount is less then dollar display just the cents and the cent symbol
        NSString *centString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i¢", earnInt];
        earnAmount.text = centString;

//if we have a number evenly divisible by 100 then we have whole dollar amount, display that properly 
    }else if(earnInt % 100 == 0){

```
    //The amount is exactly a dollar, display the whole number
    NSString *wholeDollar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%i", (earnInt/100)];
    earnAmount.text = wholeDollar;
```

//finally if we have a mixed number then put them back together with the decimal in-between.

```
}else{
    //Dollar amount is not exactly a dollar display the entire amount
    NSString *dollarString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%0d.%02d", (earnInt / 100), (earnInt % 100)];
    earnAmount.text = dollarString;

}
```

Hopefully this helps you out...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, is NSNumberFormatter.  It will only display the decimal if needed.  Example (Swift):

```
let num1: Double = 5
let num2: Double = 5.52
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: num1)))
print(numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: num2)))
```

This will print 5 and then 5.52.