# How to check if float is a whole number?

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal, rounding

The `printf` function's `%g` is able to show the whole number `3` if the float is 3.00, and will show `3.01` if the float's value isn't a round number float.

How would you do this yourself through some code, without formatting the number as a string?

Comment: is what %g is I think, I am not sure what did you ask

Comment: Can you please restate the question? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772

Comment: the function of %g but then in an actual function so I can use it outside of printf.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### There isn't really a simple answer

Integral values do have exact representations in the float and double formats. So, if it's *really* already integral, you can use:

```
f == floor(f)
```

However, if your value is the result of a calculation which at one point involved any sort of non-zero fractional part, then you will need to be concerned that you may have something very close to an integer but which isn't really, exactly, to-the-last-bit the same. You probably want to consider that to be integral.

One way this might be done:

```
fabs(f - round(f)) < 0.000001
```

And while we are on the subject, for the purists, we should note that `int i = f;` or `double i = f;` will round according to the FPU mode whereas [round(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/round) will round half-way cases away from zero.

Comment: @user2140285 - be careful. "Nearly equal" is an advanced technique. It violates transitivity (a nearly equals b and b nearly equals c does not mean that a nearly equals c) and it can mask real problems that will bite you later.

Comment: You may find the constants `FLT_EPSILON`, `DBL_EPSILON`, and `LDBL_EPSILON` (defined in `<cmath>`) handy for comparison when using this technique

Comment: Good advice here from Pete Becker and fish2000.  It is an advanced technique. (And why I said: *no simple answer* here.)

Comment: "Integral values do have exact representations in the float and double formats" - maybe this text need some correction (just to improved). double and float in real computers which used general model  ISO/IEE 754-1985 use finite number of bits for mantissa. Just look into FLT_MANT_DIG(24) and DBL_MANT_DIG(53). So it can be said that if you have 24-bits integer or 53-bits integer then representation is the same.

Comment: @fish2000: Epsilon is the distance between adjacent floats at 1.0.  e.g. `nextafter(1.0, +inf) - 1`, i.e. 1ulp at the exponent value for 1.0-1.9999, but less than 1 unit in the last place of the mantissa for any larger magnitude.  So it's the very smallest possible amount a double can differ from a whole number except zero (except when going down to 0.9999999...).  But for numbers near any other whole number, it's smaller than the minimum rounding error.  Floating point errors are typically relative, not absolute, since the format keeps a fixed number of significant figures (in binary).