# determining input type from user in a function

Tags: c++

I need to determine what user has entered into the system. Basically, if I ask user to enter his age then the user might enter float value, integer value or double value. If user inputs integer value then the program should store an integer else store double else float. Following is a basic program i wrote where user is prompt to enter his age. atm I can only store age as an integer from a function.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void input(string,void *age);

int main()
{
    int age;
    input("What is your age : ", &age);
    cout<<age;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void input(string str,void *age)
{

    int *pointer=(int*) age;
    cout<<str;
    cin>>*pointer;
}
```

What i want to do here is - you see the pointer in the function *pointer i want the program to explicitly point to the datatype that user has entered. For example if user entered a float then the function should point to a float and store its value as a float. However, the above code is not complete as the function in main() allows to have only int as a parameter I need to change this to accept any kind of data types and store accordingly.

One more thing, only if there is a way to check what user has entered before declaring a specified variable to specific type as int to store the "age" then i can get it done.

Comment: You are over-thinking this. If non-integer ages are acceptable to your program, just store it as a float.

Comment: is there a way....???

Comment: Is `12.5` a float or double?

Comment: they are all decimal values .. float is 32 bit whereas double is 64 bit

Comment: So is `12.5` a 32 bit float or is it a 64 bit double? How would you decide? Once you figure out how to decide, you can write it down in code.

Comment: You would have to read the input as a string, inspect it to determine its type and have a union of suitable types and an id to specify which format is the active one.

Answer (score 1):

> if user entered a float then the function should point to a float and store its value as a float.

Integers can be stored in a float, and it is possible to test a float or double to see if it is just an integer:

[How to check if float is a whole number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313808/how-to-check-if-float-is-a-whole-number)

Your belief that you don't want a float in cases like 3 (when you would have accepted 3.14 for the quanitity)- but rather want an integer - is really just causing you trouble.  :-/

The concept of the iostream operators is that you have declared the type you want and it sees if it can get that for you...with error handling if not.

It is conceivable that you could define your own "variant" type, or use something like [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Qt's QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html).  Then you could write an iostream input handler with some logic like *"if it can be an integer, make that the first choice.  If not try, making it a float or double.  if you have something like 3.52X7 fall back and make that a string"*.  Of course, then you wind up with a big `switch` statement on the resulting variant to see what kind of input it was that you feel you got.

A simpler-but-equivalent general method might be to read in a string for starters, and then try using routines like [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and [`stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).  Prior to C++11, similar functionality is available through Boost's [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).  Basically read in a string, then try `stoi` and catch the `invalid_argument` or `out_of_range` exceptions.  If there is no exception you've got your integer.  Otherwise try `stof` and see if that works.  Fall through to an error if not.

(In this simple case you could equivalently just try reading an integer from the stream, see if it failed, then try reading a float.  Use a union for your result.  But if you were generically trying to sift through more types to feed a variant you might want to read a string and do arbitrary processing; these are some routines to know about.)

But again...why would you do this?  What's the motivation?  Just read a float or double.

Comment: can we have an override function one who takes integer as parameter and other as float as parameter and set the parameter argument as void and then check what user has entered. But still to enter a user input we have to specify the data type. so is there a way to ask user to enter a void kind of data type??? by the way string works in this context. Taking string as user input and then checking if there is a decimal point is a convinient way of doing it to .. But i really dont get why this question has been put up buy my lecturer. he said user may enter any datatype and we have to store accord

Answer (score 1):

The input stream has no concept of the type of data entered.  You ask it for a data type, and it tries to give it to you if it can.

If you really need to determine the type (whole number vs floating-point number), you will have to read the input as a `std::string` first and parse it yourself to see if a decimal point is present, eg:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

void input(string, string*);

int main()
{
    string value;
    input("What is your age : ", &value);

    istringstream iss(value);

    char dec = use_facet<numpunct<char> >(iss.getloc()).decimal_point();
    if (value.find(dec) != std::string::npos)
    {
        double age;
        if (iss >> age)
            cout << age;
    }
    else
    {
        int age;
        if (iss >> age)
            cout << age;
    }

    if (!iss)
        cout << "Invalid Age entered";

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void input(string str, string *value)
{
    cout << str;
    getline(cin, *value);
}
```

Comment: Why the mix of C and C++ with `cout` and `getline`?