# Print all significant digits in sprintf scientific notation

Tags: c, r, printf

When R converts a large number to a string in scientific notation, it includes all significant digits and no trailing zero's. Is it possible to accomplish this in C with `sprintf`?

```
> as.character(12345e11)
[1] "1.2345e+15"
> as.character(1234500000e6)
[1] "1.2345e+15"
> as.character(1234500001e6)
[1] "1.234500001e+15"
```

I tried `sprintf(buf, "%g", val)` but this seems to include 5 decimal digits at most. I also tried to set a higher precision with `sprintf(buf, "%.18g", val)` but this will include non significant digits and trailing zeros.

Is there a way to get the behavior of `sprintf(buf, "%g", val)` but increase the 5 digit limit?

Comment: Trailing zeros are actually very significant.

Comment: I don't think it is possible at least according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf) post, which yours likely is a duplicate of.  What disturbs me is that the man page of `printf` says for the `%g` format: *“Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result”*  I could not observe this documented behavior.

Comment: @5gon12eder -- How about a carefully contrived number like `n=58.375`? Printing that with `printf("%.18g\n",n)` gives me `58.375` as expected, whereas `n=58.374` results in `58.3740000000000023` Note that .375 is equal to 3/8, so it has an exact floating point representation. Most arbitrarily chosen decimal fractions do **not** have an exact floating point representation. Hence, `%g` doesn't behave the way you might expect for those numbers.

Comment: @Jeroen -- The examples you give are all large integers. To force the integer to be printed in scientific notation, use `%.16e`. Then parse backwards from the end of the string to find the `e`, and remove any `0`s before the `e`. That's the best you can do. Note that if your number has a fractional part, then there is no solution, as discussed in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm well aware of floating point representation issues but I would not say that “58.3740000000000023” has trailing zeros.  Anyway, the OP has integers which ought to have an exact representation.  But you are right, I must have done something wrong earlier (code no longer exists).  `printf("%.10g\n", n)` (but not with 10 replaced by 18) indeed produces the desired output.  However, if you always want scientific notation, I still don't see how we can get it.  But at least, `printf` seems to do what it should.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printf width specificer to maintain precision of floating-point value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specificer-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code could use `"%.18e"` or `"%.18g"`, but the question is how large should "18" be?  Is 18 the best value?  The answer lies in `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.

`DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is the minimum number of significant digits to print to insure the *round-trip* of `double` to *string* to the same exact `double` for *all* `double`.

Recommend using format specifier `"%.*e"`.

Note that the "18" in `"%.18e"` is the number of significant digits *after* the decimal point.  So `"%.18e"` prints 19 significant digits.

---

Use `printf("%a", x);` which prints in a hexadecimal output.
For a decimal output:

```
#include <float.h>

//    sign + digit +  dp +       digits          + e + sign + expo + \0
char buf[1 + 1 +      1  + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 + 1    + 5    + 1]; 
sprintf(buf, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, x);
```

Ref [Printf width specificer to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specificer-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value/19897395#19897395)

---

A number like `y = 1.0/3.0` using the typical `double` [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format would need to see about 53 decimal digits to see its exact value.  But many of the trailing digits are not needed for a successful *round-trip*.

---

Now we know the *most* digits to print, use the below to get rid of those pesky trailing `0` digits.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *trim0(double x, char *buf) {
  sprintf(buf, "% .*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, x);
  if (isfinite(x)) {
    char *p = &buf[DBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 1];  // address of last significand digit
    char *t;
    for (t=p; *t == '0'; t--);
    memmove(t+1, p+1, strlen(p+1)+1);
  }
  return buf;
}

int main(void) {
  char buf[1 + 1 + 1 + (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1) + 1 + 1 + 5 + 1];
  printf("%s\n", trim0(1.2, buf));
  printf("%s\n", trim0(1.0/7, buf));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 1.2e+00
 1.4285714285714285e-01
```