# Printing doubles without zeroes at the end?

Tags: c, printf, double

Is there a way to print doubles in c using fprint so that the precision of the print is the least possible (So for example that an integer is always printed without decimals?)

I know that you can do something like printf("%.0f",number); But I am wondering if there is a way to use the minimum precision that makes the print exact (whenever the number can be expressed finitely in base 10 of course).

Comment: What would you expect to be printed for result of `1.0/3.0` expression?

Comment: True. 1/3.0 may have as its closest `double` some value like `0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929395`  What do you expect then?

Comment: That's why I said only when it can be expressed finitely in base 10.

Comment: Printing with with `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits is  enough to distinguish all `double` from each other.  So additional digits past that have limited value.  Code could use `printf("%.*le", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, some_double)` and that is an upper bound to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All** finite `double`, encoded in base 10 or base 2 (the usual), or base 16 can be *exactly* finitely printed in base 10.   `DBL_MIN` may take 100+ of digits to do so, but it is not infinite. `printf()` need not perform to that level.  So it ends up being custom code and of course that can "printing doubles without zeros"

Recommend `sprintf(buffer, "%.*e", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, some_double)` and post-process the buffer to remove least significant `0` as needed for a "close enough" answer to code's goal.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)