# How can I use printf command at C so that it appears only a specific number of digits or characters?

Tags: c, printf

I have to write a program which "reads" a character string, an integer and a floating-point number. Then using the `printf()` command it must appear at least 3 but no more than 7 characters or digits for each input.
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You could perhaps use `sprintf` to check that the integer fits.

Comment: You might need to give an example *Athena*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf)

Comment: How is the *character string* delimited?

Answer (score -1):

Would the section "Precision" of [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/printf-format-strings.html) be usefull for you?

It says that you could use `printf( "%.3f", 1.2348 );` to get the following output:

> 1.235

In your case you could use the precision specifier `f` with `7`.

Comment: That may produce 9 characters or more depending on the actual value of the floating point number.

Answer (score -1):

You can use fgets to limit the character read in input from the keyboard. Try this:

```
char string[7];
fgets(string, sizeof(string),stdin);
printf("%s\n",string);
```

Comment: How are you going to read the integer and the floating point value?

Comment: i show you the way to read a string and limit its number of character. you can read the integer and the floating point in any way.

Comment: No, you merely show a way to stop reading from stdin after **6** characters... That's a long shot from the OP's goal.  The question is: read a string, an integer and a floating point value from stdin, and output each in 3 to 7 characters using `printf()`.  The question might be a little imprecise and confusing, but you are not addressing it at all.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm misunderstanding the question "How can I use printf command at C so that it appears only a specific number of digits or characters?" ........