# Removing leading and trailing zeros from %f in C++

Tags: c++, regex, floating-point, string-formatting

What is the best way to remove leading and trailing zeros from C++ string formatters that use %f.
There's a similar question [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf) but that just says to use the %g formatter.

The %g formatter will output 600000000009 as 6e+11

I just want to remove the leading and trailing zeros from %f
eg:

- 000.001 -> 0.001
- 00.100 -> 0.100
- .10 -> 0.1
- 2.0 -> 2

Any thoughts/suggestions welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't `.10` go to `0.1` ???

Comment: Yeah you're right. sorry just made the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dynamic format that works in most cases is just

```
%.15g
```

that means **up to** 15 digits of precision.

An even better approach is to start from 15 digits and check back if `atof(result)` is the same as the input, incrementing the number of digits until it does match.

Using directly the maximum number of digits can be a bad idea because formatting for example `0.1` with 18 digits will bring out a representation that will look strange for the user.

Comment: This disagrees with the accepted answer on the cited question. Who's right? Can you provide some _evidence_ for your claim?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The answer is correct it works in most cases unless you have different standards of precision in you apps.