# C Optimize numeric output for FANUC G Code (truncate trailing zeroes, leave decimal)

Tags: c, cnc

Is there a format specifier in C that will output a numeric value with the decimal point left on a number, but with trailing zeroes AFTER the decimal point truncated?

The values being calculated are floats, and using %.4g gets close to the desired output, except that leaving the decimal point off the number creates problems.

The following number formats are legitimate for the machine control to read in through the RS232 port :  ( 10.0001 , 0.111 , .22 , 0. )
However, sending code including a numeral without a decimal point; for example "G00 X4" results in the machine saving the string "G00 X00.0004" . The machine interprets the input character or characters without a decimal point as being the least significant digits of a properly formed input.

I could simply use the %.4f conversion, but part of the goal is to remove the trailing zeroes. This machine has severely limited memory, and every character counts. The other option is to generate the intended output numbers, convert them to characters, and then test each number for trailing zeroes and truncate as needed. I was very much hoping for something more elegant, but I'm not finding anything in the conversion characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: floating point to BCD then to string?

Comment: `The other option is to generate the intended output numbers, convert them to characters, and then test each number for trailing zeroes and truncate as needed.` Not pretty, but that's it. See also [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf).