# Buffer overflow error and Double data type error

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

```
int i=4,a,sum;
double b,d=4.0,sum2;
char e[100],s[]="Hello";

scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%lf",&b);
fgets(e,100,stdin);
sum=i+a;
sum2=d+b;
printf("%d\n",sum);
printf("%lf\n",sum2);
printf("%s",strcat(s,e));
```

This is a sample code that gives me buffer overflow error..Where am i wrong here.Can anyone please help meIs the fgets line wrong or the printf strcat line because it does not gives me the desired output.
The output for double data should be 10.0 ,if input is 6 but it gives me 10.000000 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of how you initialized it, `s` is only large enough to hold the string `"Hello"` (6 elements total).  If you want to be able to append anything to `s`, you'll have to declare it with an explicit size:

```
char s[MAX_SIZE] = "Hello";
```

where `MAX_SIZE` is large enough to hold `"Hello"` plus whatever is in `e`.

> The output for double data should be 10.0 ,if input is 6 but it gives me 10.000000 instead

You need to specify the precision as part of the conversion specification:

```
printf( "%.1lf\n", sum2 );
```

This will limit the output to 1 digit after the decimal point.

A conversion specification basically takes the form

```
% [flags] [field-width] [. precision] [length-modifier] conversion-specifier
```

where items in square brackets are optional.  In the statement above, the *conversion-specifier* is `f`, the *length-modifier* is `l`<sup>1</sup>, and the *precision* is `.1`.

---

1. Note that this modifier has no effect on floating-point conversion specifiers (`a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G`) - they all assume a `double` argument.

Comment: Thanks that resolved the error but i still cant concatenate the strings

Comment: @AnishDhoni: What result are you expecting, and what result are you actually getting?

Comment: John Bode i want the strings to be concatenated.s already has hello now when user enters any string in e the result i want is hello + "strin user entered in e".

Comment: Precisely telling this is the first question of hackerank and i am unable to get past it i am new to programing so started at hackerank but stuck on the first question itself..They have already declared char s[]=""hackerank".I can not change it.

Comment: @AnishDhoni: the problem is that the last `scanf` call leaves a newline character in the input stream, and `fgets` exits as soon as it sees a newline, so it's not reading anything for `e`.  One quick way around this is to use `scanf` instead of `fgets` as follows: `scanf( " %99[^\n]", e );` - this will read at most 99 characters, including tabs, spaces, etc., up to (but not including) the next newline character and save it to `e`.  Note that the leading space in the format string is necessary; that tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace.

Comment: you are a genius mate!! Thanks this reolved the issue. i used scanf("%*[\n] %[^\n]", e);

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%s",strcat(s,e));
```

You are appending contents of `e` to `s`. But due to the way you initialized `s` it is not large enough to hold additional characters.

e.g.

```
s[]="Hello";

s[0] = 'H'
s[1] = 'e'
s[2] = 'l'
s[3] = 'l'
s[4] = 'o'
s[5] = 0
```

But memory starting from `s[6]` doesn't belong to you anymore - and you are trying to write contents of `e` there - aren't you?

Use larger array for `s` with defined size, e.g. `char s[SOME_SIZE]`

Comment: Giorgi, then also fix "You are concatenating e with s" because s is appended with e.

Comment: `strcat(dest, src)`: "The strcat function appends src to dst", so s is appended with e.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/ the title here says "concatenate strings"

Comment: @AnishDhoni check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf

Comment: Just a matter of (precise) language: "s is appended with e" or "e is appended to s". I fixed it in your text.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Anyway I made a change

Comment: @chux: sure will modify, i wrote in a hurry it seems

Comment: Thank you everyone..just one last question

Comment: int a,sum;
    double b,sum2;
    char e[50];
    
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    fgets(e,50,stdin);


    sum=i+a;
    sum2=b+d;
    
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    
    printf("%.1f",sum2);

    
    
    strcat(e,s);
    printf("%s",e);

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the strcat call. 
`strcat(destination, source)` appends the characters in source to those in destinations and adds a 0 character to mark the end of the string. This means that destination must have enough "free space" to fit source. In your case, destination is already "full" because you have initialized it to a buffer of 6 bytes(5 characters + the ending \0 character). If you try to write anything after the end of that buffer(e.g. `s[6]=5;`) you will write to unallocated memory. Appending anything to it with strcat will also result in writing to unallocated memory thus having unexpected results.

A sollution would be to declare s with a constant size and then strcpy something to it like this:

```
char s[100];
strcpy(s,"Hello");
```