# Remove trailling zeros from a number in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, truncate

**Example of values I am getting**

```
 12.230030
 4.000000
 400.402100
 132.000000
 53.120203
 100.0010
 45.320030
```

I want this floating values to print like this

```
12.230030
4
400.4021
132
53.120203
100.001
45.32003
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf)

Comment: This is not. I have a quick answer. I added my answer check it out

Comment: You can add your answer to an existing question then. You shouldn't ask a new question.

Comment: It is asked for C# and  this is for C++

Comment: By Mistake. I just Edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `printf` function.

```
float val=12.02300;
printf("%.8g",val);
```

Will give correct output. In this case it will output as `12.023` 
**example of other output**
For `value=400.00;`  it will output `400` 
For `value=32.122300` it will output `32.1223` .

Comment: Was this a C or a C++ question? We do not use ````printf```` in C++. C++ uses ````iostreams````. The following will do: #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
 std::vector<double> values{ 12.230030, 4.000000, 400.402100, 132.000000, 53.120203, 100.0010, 45.320030 };

 for (const double d : values) std::cout << d << "\n";

 return 0;
}