# How does postgresql cast float to numeric?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, precision, arbitrary-precision

I was wondering how Postgresql converts floating point (`float4`) values to `NUMERIC`.

I chose `0.1` as a testing value. This value is not accurately representable in base2, see https://float.exposed/0x3dcccccd for a visualization. So the stored value `0x3dcccccd` in hex for a float4 is actually not `0.1` but `0.100000001490116119385`.

However, I do not understand the output of the following commands:

```
mydb=# SELECT '0.100000001490116119385'::float4::numeric(50,50);
                       numeric                        
------------------------------------------------------
 0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(1 row)

mydb=# SELECT '0.1'::float4::numeric(50,50);
                       numeric                        
------------------------------------------------------
 0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

mydb=# SELECT '0.10000000000000000000000000000000001'::float4::numeric(50,50);
                       numeric                        
------------------------------------------------------
 0.10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why (and how) do I get `0.1` as a result in all cases? Both, `0.1` and `0.10000000000000000000000000000000001` cannot be accurately stored in a float4. The value that **can** be stored is `0.100000001490116119385` which is also the closest float4 value in both cases, but that's not what I get when casting to `numeric`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/a601366a460f68472bf70c4d94c57baa0a3ed1b2/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c):

```
Datum
float4_numeric(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    float4      val = PG_GETARG_FLOAT4(0);
    Numeric     res;
    NumericVar  result;
    char        buf[FLT_DIG + 100];

    if (isnan(val))
        PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(make_result(&const_nan));

    if (isinf(val))
    {
        if (val < 0)
            PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(make_result(&const_ninf));
        else
            PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(make_result(&const_pinf));
    }

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.*g", FLT_DIG, val);

    init_var(&result);

    /* Assume we need not worry about leading/trailing spaces */
    (void) set_var_from_str(buf, buf, &result);

    res = make_result(&result);

    free_var(&result);

    PG_RETURN_NUMERIC(res);
}
```

Comment: Not good enough. You should at least explain `FLT_DIG`.

Answer (score 1):

Further explanation of Frank Heikens's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73983470/15603477)

source code idea is get the float4 input. convert to char string, then convert to numeric.

Key function is
  `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.*g", FLT_DIG, val);`

FLT_DIG is equal to **6**.
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html

> An optional precision that gives the minimum number of digits to
> appear for the d, i, o, u, x and X conversions; the number of digits
> to appear after the radix character for the e, E and f conversions;
> t**he maximum number of significant digits for the g and G conversions;
> or the maximum number of bytes to be printed from a string in s  and S
> conversions. The precision takes the form of a period (.) followed
> either by an asterisk (*),** described below, or an optional decimal
> digit string, where a null digit string is treated as 0. If a
> precision appears with any other conversion character, the behaviour
> is undefined.

float convert to text then to numeric processs: the text after decimal delimiter can only have 6 digits precision!

snprintf example: https://legacy.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/
further post: [Avoid trailing zeroes in printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277772/avoid-trailing-zeroes-in-printf)